# how to call a function parameter within the function if it needs to be in quotes in R

Tags: r

Say I have a function

```
f1<- function(a,b){
output<-ifelse(a=='b','yes',NA)
return(output)
}
```

The function won't know to put the value of b in quotes, as I would like it to operate in the function. Is there a way around this?

UPDATE FOR CLARITY

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b<-c('T','T','T','F','F','F')
d<-data.frame(a,b)

f1<- function(condition,a,b){
    output<-ifelse(b=='condition',a,NA)
    return(output)
}
```

So, if I wanted to return a vector that includes the a values from my data frame, but only if the b values equaled T, i would write

```
f1(T,d$a,d$b)
```

And this would return the vector

```
1,2,3,NA,NA,NA
```

I'm just having a problem telling the ifelse statement to put my 'condition' term in quotes.

Comment: If you want the function to check if `a`  equals the value of `b` then I think you could just write `a == b` inside the `ifelse`?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking here

Comment: @beginneR - I know this. I'm merely asking how to reference one of the function calls inside of quotes within the function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but, perhaps, something like this helps? `f1 = function(a, b) c(a, deparse(substitute(b))); f1("a_character_argument", not_a_character_argument)`

Comment: Could you give an example of the type of arguments you actually want to compare in the function and the expected output?

Comment: Out of curiosity, who clicked on the "this question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" button?

Comment: If you use your function like this `f1("T", a, b)` you already get the correct output: `[1]  1  2  3 NA NA NA`. So you just need to tell R that `T` is not an object but a character by using `""` in the function call.

Comment: Voted to re-open this question, as the OP has added sufficient information to solve the problem.

Comment: thanks @beginneR ! That totally works. I figured it was super simple. Sorry to irritate everyone with my vague question.

Comment: Side note: it seems that you actually have logical entries which can be `TRUE` or `FALSE`. In that case you could replace the current character entries `"T"` and `"F"` with `TRUE` and `FALSE` or `T` and `F` (without parentheses) in the definition of b and use the same in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was answered in comments, but it's much better practice to get used to working with logicals, i.e., `T` or `TRUE` and `F` or `FALSE`. If you have `b = c(T, T, F)`, you don't need to do `ifelse(b == T, ...)`, you can just use `ifelse(b, ...)`. You can also easily negate with `!`.

Your example could be much simplified as such:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b<-c('T','T','T','F','F','F')
good.b <- as.logical(b)

# Now some sample output
> good.b
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> a[good.b]
[1] 1 2 3
> a[!good.b]
[1] 4 5 6
> a[!good.b] <- NA # This line does what your function does
> a
[1]  1  2  3 NA NA NA
```